# Swagger UI not showing all the fields from user defined model

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am learning Swagger. I have a simple Spring Boot REST API to display employee. The Employee model has an association of employee addresses. All I am trying is to display the employee details for the documentation using Swagger.

This is my Employee model:

```
package com.example.documentation.model;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee<T> {
    @Schema(type = "int", description = "id for employee")
    private int id;

    @Schema(type = "string", description = "name of employee")
    private String name;
    private List<T> listOfAddresses;
    public Employee(int id, String name, List<T> listOfAddresses) {
        this.listOfAddresses = listOfAddresses;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<T> getListOfAddresses() {
        listOfAddresses = (List<T>) Arrays.asList(new Address(2201,"Street 1","UB12 
1TT"), new Address(3201,"Street 1","KK12 1TP"));
        return listOfAddresses;
    }

    public void setListOfAddresses(List<T> listOfAddresses) {
        this.listOfAddresses = listOfAddresses;
    }}
```

where Address is a normal POJO with houseNumber, Streetname and postcode.

Below is my controller:

```
package com.example.documentation.controller;

import com.example.documentation.model.Address;
import com.example.documentation.model.Employee;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    private Employee<Address> employee;

    @RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
    @Operation(
            tags = {"Employee"}
    )

    public Employee<Address> getEmployeeDetailsById(@PathVariable(name = "id", required = true) int id,
                                                    @PathVariable(name = "name", required = false) String name)  {

        List<Address> list = Arrays.asList(new Address(101,"T1","Test 1"),
                new Address(201,"T2","Test 2"));
        employee = new Employee<>(101,"David", list);

        return employee;
    }
}
```

I am using Gradle.

When I access Swagger UI, I see the following:

[image]

As you can see the ID and the name of the employee is missing. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You don't need `Employee<Address>` as return type, it's enough just to return `Employee` type.